# objective-c google static map returns nil

Tags: objective-c, google-maps, uiimage

this is my code:

```
#define GOOGLE_STATIC_MAP_IMAGE @"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=%@&zoom=15&size=320x150&maptype=roadmap&markers=color:green|label:H|%@"

-(UIImage*)GetGoogleStaticMap
{
    NSString* coordinates = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f,%f", latitude, longitude];
    NSString *stringURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:GOOGLE_STATIC_MAP_IMAGE, coordinates, coordinates]; //coordinates x2 = for the center & the marker
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:stringURL];
    NSData *imageData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];

    return image;
}
```

if I paste stringURL to the browser i get the desired result, but imageData returns nil - ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may have returned nil because of certain characters in the string.

Try calling `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding` on your `stringURL` before creating the `url` object.

For example:

```
newStringURL = [stringURL stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```